# Как указать CORS-заголовки для http.FileServer?

Tags: http, golang, cors

Подскажите пожалуйста, как указать заголовки для `http.FileServer`? Т. е.,  понимаю, что нужно прописать это:

```golang
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Но куда не понимаю. Вот весь код:

```golang
func initServer(pathToStatic string, c chan <- string ) {
  port := "46424"
  http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix(strings.TrimRight("/static/", "/"), http.FileServer(http.Dir(pathToStatic))))

  log.Printf("Serving %s on HTTP port: %s\n", pathToStatic, port)
  c <- fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%s/static/", port)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Заверните» свой обработчик:

```golang
var orig = http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
var wrapped = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    // …

    orig.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})

http.Handle("/static/", wrapped)
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать : )  